# str to int issue 'int' object not callable when var set for multiplication

Tags: python

Some of the code can be ignored, I am trying to turn a str into int, while doing so I seem to be getting this error. 'int' object is not callable

llb and lw are not mentioned anywhere else in the code only in this section. and it's the first and only time they are set.

I have been fiddling with this for hrs now and can't seem to figure it out. Nothing else with this error seems to match the same scenario with my error.

llb is normally set to something simple like 2 from a post

```
@app.route('/printlab', methods=['POST'])
def printlab():
 if request.method == 'POST':
     lfname = request.form['first_name']
     llname = request.form['last_name']
     lstate = request.form['state']
     lcity = request.form['city']
     laddress = request.form['shipping_address']
     lzip = request.form['zip']
     llb = request.form['lbs']
     loz = request.form['ozs']
     lw = (int(llb)*16)
     return lw
```

edit: added error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, 
in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, 
in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, 
in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 921, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 59, in _run_wsgi_app
return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 923, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: I bet that somewhere, you have a variable in scope that is an `int` object called `int = 123` or whatever...

Comment: The only time int is ever used is right there in that code. I checked that before posting :/

Comment: It looks like this: `app_rv = app(environ, start_response)` is the line throwing the error, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View functions are supposed to return a template render call, or a redirect, or some other sort of HTML response.  Your function returns a plain integer.

This return value is being passed up into the Flask framework, which can't handle it.

Comment: This makes sense, I was doing this just to test the code before I pass it to the next step. Had no clue return didn't allow that. Thanks!